# Wordpress - category pagination not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to utilize the default category pages for ajax loads.  I'm stripping the template pages down to only return html that I want/need.

The caveat to this is I have to generate a new "all categories" template file, rewrite $wp_query and then pull all posts.

The issue I'm having is the routing for the `/page/` query var isn't flowing through to the template.

Example:

`http://example.com/category/all` routes to `category-all.php`

`http://example.com/category/all/page/2` gives a 404

Here's some code:

```
// Define custom query parameters
$posts_args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$posts_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$posts = new WP_Query( $posts_args );

$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $posts;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'news' );
    endwhile;
endif;
// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is get_query_var('page') giving results?
Try changing it to:

```
get_query_var('paged')
```

Comment: Here was the final solution for the query:  `$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

  $args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
   'paged' => $paged,
  );
  `